# What does AREL stand for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, arel, relational-algebra

What does AREL stand for? I couldn't find what's the meaning of this acronym anywhere.

Comment: Just move your mouse over the arel tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This?  https://github.com/nkallen/arel  "A RELational algebra"

See also: <strike>http://magicscalingsprinkles.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/why-i-wrote-arel/</strike> http://web.archive.org/web/20120718093140/http://magicscalingsprinkles.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/why-i-wrote-arel/

Comment: Looks like the Wordpress blog is missing recent posts... I found a backup on Archive.org and fixed the link. It's an interesting and worthwhile read. (In case my edit isn't accepted: http://web.archive.org/web/20120718093140/http://magicscalingsprinkles.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/why-i-wrote-arel/).

Answer (score 2):

Or, perhaps "Active Relation": http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html